# Expression for the sum of the roots of a polynomial of degree n to the power of k

Tags: functions, polynomials, summation, roots

I am trying to find a function f(m) that given a power m returns the sum of the roots to the power of m.
$$(x-a_1)(x-a_2)(x-a_3)...(x-a_n)=0$$
$$f(m)=\sum_{k=1}^n{(a_ k)^m}$$
I attempted doing it manually for small values of n however I wasn't able to spot a pattern after m=3. For m=2 using a quadratic in the form of $x^2+bx+c=0$ I got $b^2-2c$ but that was as far as I got.

Comment: lookup [Netwon's identities](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_identities) and see whether it is what you want...

Answer (score 1):

If $\,p(x):=x-c_1,\,$ then $\,f(0)=1\,$ and $\,f(m)=c_1^m\,$
which satisfies
$\, f(m+1) = c_1f(m).\,$ Next, if $\,p(x):=x^2-c_1x-c_2,\,$ then
$\, f(0)=2,\,f(1)=c_1\,$ and
$\, f(m+2) = c_1f(m+1)+c_2f(m).\,$ This easily generalizes.
All you need is the first few initial values of $\,f(m)\,$
for $\,m=0,\dots,n\,$ where $\,n\,$ is the degree of $\,p(x).\,$

Answer (score 0):

I used *Mathematica* function:

```
SymmetricReduction[a_1^3+a_2^3+a_3^3,{a_1,a_2,a_3}]
```

$x^3+ax^2+bx+c=0$

If roots are $a_1,a_2,a_3$ then

$$a_1^3+a_2^3+a_3^3=\left(a_1+a_2+a_3\right)^3-3 \left(a_1 a_2+a_3 a_2+a_1 a_3\right) \left(a_1+a_2+a_3\right)+3 a_1 a_2 a_3$$

$$a_1^3+a_2^3+a_3^3=-(a^3+3ab+3c)$$

Fourth degree

$x^3+ax^3+bx^2+cx+d=0$

$$a_1^4+a_2^4+a_3^4+a_4^4=\left(a_1+a_2+a_3+a_4\right){}^4-4 \left(a_1 a_2+a_3 a_2+a_4 a_2+a_1 a_3+a_1 a_4+a_3 a_4\right) \left(a_1+a_2+a_3+a_4\right){}^2+4 \left(a_1 a_2 a_3+a_1 a_4 a_3+a_2 a_4 a_3+a_1 a_2 a_4\right) \left(a_1+a_2+a_3+a_4\right)+2 \left(a_1 a_2+a_3 a_2+a_4 a_2+a_1 a_3+a_1 a_4+a_3 a_4\right){}^2-4 a_1 a_2 a_3 a_4$$

$$a_1^4+a_2^4+a_3^4+a_4^4=a^4-4 a^2 b+4 a c+2 b^2-4 d$$

Fifth degree

$$a_1^5+a_2^5+a_3^5+a_4^5+a_5^5=5 a_1 a_2 a_3 a_4 a_5+\left(a_1+a_2+a_3+a_4+a_5\right)^5-5 \left(a_1+a_2+a_3+a_4+a_5\right){}^3 \left(a_1 a_2+a_3 a_2+a_4 a_2+a_5 a_2+a_1 a_3+a_1 a_4+a_3 a_4+a_1 a_5+a_3 a_5+a_4 a_5\right)+5 \left(a_1+a_2+a_3+a_4+a_5\right) \left(a_1 a_2+a_3 a_2+a_4 a_2+a_5 a_2+a_1 a_3+a_1 a_4+a_3 a_4+a_1 a_5+a_3 a_5+a_4 a_5\right)^2+5 \left(a_1+a_2+a_3+a_4+a_5\right){}^2 \left(a_1 a_2 a_3+a_1 a_4 a_3+a_2 a_4 a_3+a_1 a_5 a_3+a_2 a_5 a_3+a_4 a_5 a_3+a_1 a_2 a_4+a_1 a_2 a_5+a_1 a_4 a_5+a_2 a_4 a_5\right)-5 \left(a_1 a_2+a_3 a_2+a_4 a_2+a_5 a_2+a_1 a_3+a_1 a_4+a_3 a_4+a_1 a_5+a_3 a_5+a_4 a_5\right) \left(a_1 a_2 a_3+a_1 a_4 a_3+a_2 a_4 a_3+a_1 a_5 a_3+a_2 a_5 a_3+a_4 a_5 a_3+a_1 a_2 a_4+a_1 a_2 a_5+a_1 a_4 a_5+a_2 a_4 a_5\right)-5(a_1+a_2+a_3+a_4+a_5)\left(a_1 a_2 a_3 a_4+a_1 a_2 a_5 a_4+a_1 a_3 a_5 a_4+a_2 a_3 a_5 a_4+a_1 a_2 a_3 a_5\right.$$